# React.js Using the same FORM for creating a NEW db object and EDIT various objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux

I have a simple input field like this:

```
<TextField
    required
    variant="standard"
    type="string"
    margin="normal"
    fullWidth = {false}
    size="small"
    id="orgName"
    placeholder="Organisation Name"
    label="Name"
    name="orgName"
    // defaultValue={orgData ? orgData.orgName : ""}
    //inputRef={(input) => this.orgName = input}
    value={this.state.orgName || ""}
    onChange={this.handleChange("orgName")}
    error={this.state.errors["orgName"]}
  />
```

I want to use the same input field for new and update? For new I just set the state to empty, and save the values. Which works fine. Now I have a select dropdown to edit the previously saved objects.

My problem is with editing, and I am tearing my head out trying to find the any way to do this. All these  are the corresponding issues:

1. If i set the state from props - any edited changes are being reset
2. If i don't set the state from props, I get all blank fields, which is incorrect.
3. If I use defaultValue to load the form inputs from props, then its only called once. And it does not reload when I change the object to be edited.
4. If i just use onChange handler for, the form gets creepy slow, with many inputs on page
5. If I use refs, I am not able to reset the refs to reload the input when the object to be edit changes.
6. I have managed to make it work with componentWillReceiveProps, but it is deprecated, and react website is saying its dangerous to use it.

   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if (nextProps.orgData !== this.props.orgData) {
   this.setState({
   "orgName": nextProps.orgData.orgName,
   "orgPath": nextProps.orgData.orgPath,
   "orgAddress": nextProps.orgData.orgAddress,
   "orgPhone": nextProps.orgData.orgPhone,
   "orgEmail": nextProps.orgData.orgEmail,
   })

   }
   }

So how can I actually create an editable form where the values have to be loaded from props for different instances from db, but they have to controlled by the state. **There has to someplace where I have to check saying "hey if the props have changed, reset the state with the new props for edit???**

This has been the most frustrating experience using react for me. How are there no examples anywhere on how to build a simple form to create new, and editable object using react and redux. It just seems overly complicated to do such a simple thing, the whole thing just sucks!

Comment: Use ```formik``` and ```redux``` together, there's less headache with that combination.

Answer (score 1):

> There has to someplace where I have to check saying "hey if the props have changed, reset the state with the new props for edit???

Yes you can use `React.useEffect` hook on the special prop or Array of props, then when that/those prop(s) change the internal hook function will be fire.

e.g. :

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  let [myState,setMyState]= React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    setMyState(props.prop1);
  },[props.prop1]);

  return ...
}
```